# Java Multiple Sets within a Map

Tags: java, set, maps

I am reading from a CSV file which contains data about Hills, all the reading etc works fine but now I want to create a map which associates the "County Name" (A column header in the file) with all the hills that have the county name in it.

I am along the right path, because my code works for the first countyName, but the problem is when my for loop If statement goes to the else statement, I want it to technically create another set (clearing the previous values) and assigning the new hill data with the county name

My output is:

```
{Perth and Kinross=[16,Knock of Crieff,Perth and Kinross,279.0,56.389329,-3.826973, 3,Creag Uchdag,Perth and Kinross,879.0,56.465278,-4.098107]}
```

So it has all the hills with "Perth and Kinross" in it. So now my next county name is "Stirling" for example so the map should end up like

```
{Perth and Kinross=[16,Knock of Crieff,Perth and Kinross,279.0,56.389329,-3.826973, 3,Creag Uchdag,Perth and Kinross,879.0,56.465278,-4.098107], Stirling=[7,Meall Buidhe,Stirling,719.0,56.419004,-4.308645]}
```

What I'm unsure about is how to create another set without clearing the values stored for Perth and Kinross

My code is:

```
    Map<String, Set<Hill>> hillsByCounty = new HashMap<>();

        if (h.getCounty().equals(countyName)) {
            hillsByCounty.get(countyName);
            currentSet.add(h);
            hillsByCounty.put(countyName, currentSet);

        } else {

            countyName = h.getCounty();
            currentSet.clear();
            currentSet.add(h);

        }
    }

    return hillsByCounty;
}
```

Where exactly is it going wrong. I have a feeling it is the clear function but i'm not sure how else i would do this.

My current code prints out:

```
{Perth and Kinross=[7,Meall Buidhe,Stirling,719.0,56.419004,-4.308645], Stirling=[7,Meall Buidhe,Stirling,719.0,56.419004,-4.308645]}
```

As its overwriting the set. What would be my workaround?

Comment: "why isn't this code working?" kind of questions are off-topic here. Please use a debugger to find the error or come back if you have a concrete problem to solve.

Comment: @Vampire  its not that im saying it isn't working i'm wondering why my set is being overwritten. I edited and added a code snippet of what my code does, and it also shows above what i want it to do. I just dont know where my code is messing up

Comment: Sure, that's what a debugger is for with which you can step through your code to see where the error is. Your code **is** not working and this is a classical question that you should not post here but use a debugger instead. As the problem is rather obvious I posted an answer anyway, but please don't post "why isn't this code working as I expect it" here, they are off-topic according to SO rules.

Answer (score 0):

You reuse the same set. So if your county changes, you clear the set and fill it with the next county. Instead you should create a new set. As long as you reuse the same set, well, you reuse the same set, empty it and fill something else in it. `hillsByCounty.put(...)` does not clone the set, but just stores a reference.

Comment: Well you see how you are saying create a new set, since it's a CSV file it obviously contains 100+ county names, so by making a new set wont it mean i can only have 2 sets?

Comment: Why to you think so?

Comment: Well because you're saying that, if i reuse the same set and empty it and fill it with something else, wont the total outcome be the same unless i have a new set for every county name

Comment: Of course, that's what I said. Your problem is that you are reusing the same set when you actually should create a new Set per county.

Answer (score 0):

The value for each entry of the map is the same set so every modification on one set will also appear at the other entries.
You can check for an existing set in the loop body:

```
for (Hill h : hills) {
    Set<Hill> currentSet = hillsByCountry.get(h.getCountry());
    if (currentSet == null) {
        currentSet = new HashSet<>();
        hillsByCountry.put(h.getCountry(), currentSet);
    }
    currentSet.add(h);
}
```

Comment: I see so this checks whether or not there is an existing set, and if it is, then it creates a new set?

Comment: If there is **no** existing set, it creates a new one ;)